# Port Closed after portforwarding

Tags: networking

I am trying to open a minecraft server. So I port forwarded my port 25565 for my private IP 192.168.1.35. Yet when I check with online scanners while the server is running the port seems to be closed. This started happening right after I reset my router because I had forgotten its password.

What I had tried so far:

- Closed and reopened the router and the computer few times
- Closed my firewall

Router is a Archer C5v

Edit: screenshot of the router settings

[image]

Comment: `after I reset my router` -- Just to be sure: did you configure the forwarding *after* the reset? Please check if `192.168.1.35` is the right IP. Did you configure a static lease?

Comment: I assume you created a virtual server, per the [manual](https://static.tp-link.com/resources/document/Archer_C5_V2_UG.pdf). Please add a screenshot of its settings. The manual also has this cryptic note in chapter 5.10.1: "If you want the Virtual Servers configuration take effect, please make sure the NAT is enabled". The preceding section 5.9 is about "NAT Boost", to which this might refer.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes I did it after the reset and yes 192.168.1.35 is the correct address

Comment: @harrymc Mine doesn't list as a "virtual server" but like "port forwarding", I believe they are the same thing.

Comment: `Closed my firewall` I'm understanding it as you've closed the firewall on the computer. Did you check the firewall on the router?

Comment: Try instead of port 25565 to use one below 1000.

Comment: Please add the current DHCP leases on your router to the question.

Comment: Using a port below 1000 didn't work (I used 754).  I also tried closing the firewall of my router. What do you mean by DHCP leases.

Comment: Something interesting to note is that some port scanners online show that port is filtered (I guess by a firewall or something) while others show either as closed or they time out. If the port is filtered something is wrong with my firewalls but I cannot confirm if that is the problem here.